# Select the first radio button of multiple radio buttons groups with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to automatically select the first radio button of multiple radio buttons groups.

```
<div class="element">
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="3">
</div>

<div class="element">
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="3">
</div>
```

Here is the thing, while this works:

```
$('.element').each(function(){
    $(this).find('input[type=radio]:first').attr('checked', true);
});
```

I can't figure out why I can't make it work using the :first selector using the each() method

The code below doesn't work: it only selects the first radio button in the first div, can you tell me why?

```
$('.element input[type=radio]:first').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('checked', true);
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first selector loops through each `.element`. The second selector loops through each `element input[type=radio]:first`, which consists of only one element.

I've translated your code to a human-readable sequence:

1. Select `.element`
   Go through each `.element`
   Find the first occurence of a radio input element
   Set `checked=true`.
2. Select the first radio input element which is a child of `.element`.
   Loop through each element which matches the selector (just one)
   Set `checked=true`.

---

Alternative ways:

```
//Alternative method
$('element').each(function(){
    $('input[type=radio]', this).get(0).checked = true;
});

//Another method
$('element').each(function(){
    $('input[type=radio]:first', this).attr('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: so this means I can only use the first solution to select the first radio button of each .element ? There is no more direct way to do it using :first selector?

Comment: if the radio group is the same, you might do a click() (on the first item) instead of a attr or checked

Comment: I would suggest adding a .click() to the end of the input selector to ensure that the form is reading it as an input.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use the `:first-child` selector. As opposed to `:first`, which only returns the first of the matched elements, `:first-child` will return any element that is the first child of its parent element:

```
//returns the first radio button in group1, and the first one in group2 as well.
$('.element input[type=radio]:first-child');
```

See Rob W's answer for an explanation of why your code isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Try using nth-child:

```
$('.element').each(function(){
    $(this).find('input[type=radio]:nth-child(1)').attr('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with Radio Button **Class Name**

```
<div class="element">
<input class="radio_btn" type="radio" name="group1" value="1">
<input class="radio_btn" type="radio" name="group1" value="2">
<input class="radio_btn" type="radio" name="group1" value="3">
</div>

<div class="element">
<input class="radio_btn" type="radio" name="group2" value="1">
<input class="radio_btn" type="radio" name="group2" value="2">
<input class="radio_btn" type="radio" name="group2" value="3">
</div>

<script>
$('.radio_btn:first').attr('checked', true);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, `first-child` did not work, and I did not use `each` for loop the elements,

This worked for me,

```
$('.element input[type=radio]:first').attr('checked', true);
```